# Show all folders and files that are not added to the .csproj file

Tags: visual-studio

I have trouble finding out how to see or filter all files in the solution explorer, that are not added to the .csproj project file.

In the 'navbar' of the solution explorer, there is the option to show all files, what shows me also files that are not added to the .csproj file.

**Is there a way to show or filter unadded folders or files in the solution explorer?**

This would save me a lot of time. Because with every update this project gets, I have to look through the project file in the solution explorer and add every unadded folder or file by hand.

Answer (score 1):

The "Show All Files" button does not appear if you are selecting the Solution itself. If you select an underlying Project, or any of the folders/files in the project, the button will display:

[image: Show all files button]

This button should be there in your solution. It is in my visual studio 2017

Comment: I know, thx! But I have still to open every folder to see the files, that are not added.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case that just shouldn't happen if the project is being updated properly.
What this means is, that when someone updates the projects and adds new files, that person doesn't check-in the relevant changes to the .csproj.

As far as I know, there's no way to list all files that haven't been included.
Instead of trying to fix this problem, rather try to fix the underlying problem: files that are being added to the project, but not to the .csproj.